# Spinner without Dropdown

Tags: android

How to remove the dropdown from the spinner and when clicked on that spinner other activity or may be someother xml layout file should be displayed (like wheel widget) and after selecting particular item from that wheel widget this activity should be invisible.

Comment: I hope you're not implementing the iOS wheel in android :))

Comment: No sir, i want a simple spinner view with no drop down.. something like drop down should be disabled.. but when i click on that spinner it should call some other activity

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the `dropdown` of your `Spinner` you can use the following code in your layout.xml file for your `Spinner` element :

```
   android:background="@null"
```

For taking the click action on your spinner you can do the following :

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //....
            mSpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
               View view, int pos, long id) {
            //maybe start another activity...
        }     
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using exactly Spinner view you can use Button view and give it a spinner like image and in onClick show the layout you want .